# update statement using loop over tuple of query and data fails in psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, functional-programming, sql-update, psycopg2

I have created a mini functional pipeline which creates an update statement with regex and then passes the statement and the data to pycopg2 to execute.

If I copy paste the statement outside of the loop it works, if I try to loop over all statements I get an error.

```
# Function to create statement


def psycopg2_regex_replace_chars(table, col, regex_chars_old, char_new):
    query = "UPDATE {} SET {} = regexp_replace({}, %s , %s, 'g');".format(table, col, col)
    data = (regex_chars_old, char_new)
    return (query, data)


# Create functions with intelligible names


replace_separators_with_space = partial(psycopg2_regex_replace_chars,regex_chars_old='[.,/[-]]',char_new=' ')
replace_amper_with_and = partial(psycopg2_regex_replace_chars, regex_chars_old='&', char_new='and')


# create funcs_list


funcs_edit = [replace_separators_with_space,
              replace_amper_with_and]
```

So far, so good.

## This works

```
stmt = "UPDATE persons SET name = regexp_replace(name, %s , %s, 'g');"
data = ('[^a-zA-z0-9]', ' ')
cur.execute(stmt, data)
conn.commit()
```

## This fails

```
tables = ["persons"]
cols = ["name", "dob"]

for table in tables:
   for col in cols:
        for func in funcs_edit:
            query, data = func(table=table, col=col)
            cur.execute(query, data)
            conn.commit()
```

## error

````
<ipython-input-92-c8ba5d469f88> in <module>
      6         for func in funcs_edit:
      7             query, data = func(table=table, col=col)
----> 8             cur.execute(query, data)
      9             conn.commit()

ProgrammingError: function regexp_replace(date, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE persons SET dob = regexp_replace(dob, '[.,/[-]]' , ' ...
                                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.```
````

Comment: The error says it all: your column `dob` is of type `date`, not `text` as [required](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html)

Comment: Why do you want to remove non alphanumeric characters from a `date`  column?(dob)